# I am trying to connect my local springboot appplication to my heroku postgress db

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, heroku

I am trying to connect my local spring-boot application to my Heroku Postgres DB.
When I tried this using the creds available on Heroku, I get the following error

Error: SEVERITY_LOCALIZED=FATAL, SEVERITY_NON_LOCALIZED=FATAL, CODE=28000, MESSAGE=no pg_hba.conf entry for host "myhost", user "myuser", database "mydb", SSL off, FILE=auth.c, LINE=520, ROUTINE=ClientAuthentication

Following is how I am providing the connection details to my app
spring:
r2dbc:
host: my host from heroku
port: 5432
username: username
password: password
database: database

I am providing these values in the application.yml file

Comment: Hi! Have U find any solution?

Comment: get same thing... bd result result but i see theses lines in the log...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an application on Heroku and found an article on configuring Spring Boot and r2dbc to use PostgreSQL on Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-data-r2dbc-with-azure-postgresql#configure-spring-boot-to-use-azure-database-for-postgresql

I added `spring.r2dbc.properties.sslMode=REQUIRE` to my application.properties and it also worked on Heroku.